# How to write the algorithm of Selection Sort for sorting list of elements in descending order using cpp?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

**I am trying to print the sorted list in a descending order.**
This code below is giving me the default ascending order i want the way to make it in descending order.
You can also check the code the [thrownbin](https://throwbin.io/apkoy6h)

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class selection {
int siz, *ar;
public:
void getInput();
void selectSort();
void display();
};
void selection :: getInput()    {

cout<<endl<<"enter array size ";
cin>>siz;

ar = new int[siz];
for(int k=0; k<siz; k++)     {
cout<<endl<<"Enter array Value ";
cin>>ar[k] ;
 }
 }
void selection ::display()     {
 for(int k=0; k<siz; k++)
cout<<endl<<ar[k];
}
void selection ::selectSort()       {
int k,m,t;
for(k=0; k<siz-1; k++)     {
for(m=k+1; m<siz; m++)
if( ar[k]>ar[m])   {
t = ar[k];
ar[k]=ar[m];
ar[m]=t;
}  } }
int main()    {
selection *s = new selection();
s->getInput();
cout<<endl<<"Array values before sorting ";
s->display();
s->selectSort();
cout<<endl<<"Array values after sorting ";
s->display();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just print the array backwards? Or change your > comparison  to <

Comment: Please explain what you mean?!

Comment: Well your algorithm is checking if one index is greater than the next element and if it is you are swapping it, if you want the largest element at the beginning then if the first index is larger than the second index do nothing else swap them.  Alternatively, printing your array starting from the last index and decreasing your loop counter will print it backwards

Comment: I posted it as an answer :)

Comment: Please format your code if you want anyone to read it. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Ok Eckhardt i will do that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your algorithm is checking if one index is greater than the next element and if it is you are swapping it, if you want the largest element at the beginning then if the first index is larger than the second index do nothing else swap them. Alternatively, printing your array starting from the last index and decreasing your loop counter will print it backwards